# How to put values of textbox into variable in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I want to add values to my `MySql` database using `PHP`. The values I want to add, will come from the text-boxes of a form. I tried `$variable = $_POST['formElementName']` and used `$variable` to insert values. But it doesn't work.

### Question:

How can I put the values of the text-boxes into variables?

Thanks.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php

Comment: $_post['fieldname'] is correct , Are u sending POST or GET request ?

Comment: I'm using POST. I want to add values after button click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just want to elaborate what @Kyle wrote

Note: The form method is POST

HTML part

```
 <form action="your_php_file_name.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="first_name" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
 </form>
```

PHP part: The file name is: your_php_file_name.php

```
<?php
     //A good practice to check the type of HTTP request
     $fname = $_POST['first_name'];
?>
```

Some good practices

1. Check the HTTP request type sent from the client side. (I find it a good way)
2. Sanitize the variables before inserting.

Comment: This worked. Thank you. :) But i have another error.

"Warning: mysql_close() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Web Exam\signupResult.php on line 30"

What does this mean?

Comment: Edit your question and paste your code

Comment: This was sorted. Thanks :))

Answer (score 1):

Use below code for the form

```
 <form name="form-name" action="" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="fieldname1" value="" />
  <input type="text" name="fieldname2" value="" />
 </form>
```

and for php manipulation at server end, you will get values in `$_POST` i.e.

```
$_POST['fieldname1']  and $_POST['fieldname2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea:

Client-side:

```
<input type="text" name="first_name">
```

Server-side:

```
$var = $_POST["first_name"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to Kyle's answer above, Make sure you have `value="Something"` set, otherwise it will return nothing.

```
<input type="text" name="first_name" value="Testing">
```

Server Side

```
$var = $_POST["first_name"];
```

For debugging I use:

```
print_r($_POST)
```

This will return all the POST values set and is really handy.